# Events list for Shopware 6?

Tags: list, events, controller, dispatcher, shopware

Is someone aware if list is present of every Event in Shopware 6, something similar to controller_action_postdispatch in Magento 2? 
I need a Shopware 6 event which is triggered on every controller action so i can redirect the customer to login form if it`s not logged in.

Comment: Peter Jaap Blaakmeer created a list of Shopware events on this page: https://www.p16r.nl/2020-09-29-shopware-6-list-of-events/

Answer (score 5):

Shopware 6 is using Symfony for routing. So, you could just use a fitting Symfony event. Perhaps you can find one at this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html